# send email to customer only after successful payment through paytm in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php, payment-gateway

I have a website in magento(1.9.3) with multiple vendor and paytm as an payment solution. The problem that i am facing is when i am placing the order a order confirmation mail is being sent to the vendor even before the payment is being made and if the order is success from paytm, this time the admin and the user receive a invoice mail but not the vendor.

So if i stop the mail at the time of order placement from admin, the vendor won't receive any mail of order and so he won't be notified.

So is there a way to send invoice mail to all the vendor, user and admin after the successful payment from paytm.

Thank you.

Comment: You can create a module to capture the payment success full and send the email there in the observer.

Comment: Please share paytm model folder codes

Comment: than how you get information related to pepoles who faced problems in paytm payment page ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new custom module. In the event observer capture the even `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` and create a method in the observer and complete your logic in the method.

**1 ) here is custom config.xml for call observer file**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<Namespace_Modulename>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</Namespace_Modulename>
</modules>
<frontend>
<events>            
    <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
        <observers>
            <Namespace_Modulename_Customevent>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>customFunction</method>
            </Namespace_Modulename_Customevent>
        </observers>
    </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
</events>
</frontend>
```

**2 ) create observer.php file inside your module/Model directory and paste this code**

```
<?php
class Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer{
public function customFunction(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
 //here you can add your custom code
}
}
```

for further reading use this [link](http://dltr.org/blog/magento/495/Magento-force-sending-emails-after-order-successful)

Answer (score 1):

You can `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` event as Mujahidh says.

***checkout_onepage_controller_success_action*** event give **`only  array of order ids`** `order_ids`.

[***`Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_onepage_controller_success_action', array('order_ids' => array($lastOrderId)));`***](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php#L294)

```
public function [YourFunction]($observer)
{
    $order_ids=$observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
    if(!is_array($order_ids)):
        return;
    endif;

        foreach ($order_ids as $eachOrderId) {

            $order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($eachOrderId);   
            if($order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode()== [PAYTM)_PAYMENT_METHOD_CODE] )
            {
              // SEND ORDER EMAIL
              $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
            }
        }
}
```